# Register for notifications for application's viewDidAppear/etc.?

Tags: objective-c, ios, notifications, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

Is it possible in iOS to register on AppDelegate for notifications for all viewDidAppear which happen in this app? I want to have register for those to do some analytics processing for my app, without the need to explicitly trigger my class from every single viewDidAppear.
Any suggestions how this could be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Hijack `objc_msgSend()`. Compare selector to `@selector(viewDidAppear)`. Perform action. Call original function. (Yeah, sorry, I've come from JB world...)

Comment: @H2CO3: What is "JB world"? Jailbreaking?

Comment: @H2CO3: What's the connection between that and the runtime hacking you mentioned?

Comment: @JoshCaswell it's not permitted to do in the AppStore.

Comment: @H2CO3: What a ridiculous rule.

Comment: @JoshCaswell oh yes, reasonable claim... Sorry, just didn't understand you (and I really don't expect any good from people, if you know what I mean...). Yes, it's a pity, and there are similar no-brain limitations (including the lack of homebrew and Windows/Linux SDKs) which I'll never understand nor tolerate. If I ever become CEO of Apple, I'll end all these... :)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to subclass UIView and register the notification and post it from that subclass.  All your views in your app would need to be instances of your subclass.